# How to create web application tutorial/self-study guide mode. Z-index property issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating tutorial mode for my application. I have a full screen div, covering all the website area with black color with 80% opacity. How can I cut a area in that div to show choosen element? Remember I want to block other elements. I mean something like this:
[image]

I tried a lot of things with z-index and it sometimes work, but it's generally not possible solution. Sometimes parent of highlithed element needs to have z-index property, sometimes parent has background-color (not element inside) and it's unvisible on higher z-index because it has not own background-color.

How can I solve that problem?

PS: Here I created a JSFiddle for example header problem: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6rpzrnxs/)

```css
header
{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 80px;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.avatar
{
 transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 border-radius: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 20px;
 margin-left: 80px;
 background-color: red;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 cursor: pointer;
 position: relative;
 filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,1));
}

.fullscreen-flex
{ 
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 100;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.tutorial-task
{
 position: relative;
 z-index: 105;
 background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="avatar tutorial-task">
  </div>
    <div class="avatar">
  </div>
</header>

<div class="fullscreen-flex">

</div>
```

PS2: The problem is with fixed header. But it MUST to be fixed.

Comment: @SahilDhir I added it how you said.

Comment: @SahilDhir Of course not. Look at avatar with class "tutorial-task". It is not clickable.

Comment: Ok i just checked your example code.. This is happeneing becasue of position:fixed to header element.. which is causing th child div to not come up.

Comment: Setting the z-index of the element you want to show above is likely to cause issues, if you want this to work for every element, no matter what its actual current formatting is. // If you want to actually “cut out” parts of that overlay, then a CSS/SVG mask would be the way to do that - but you will have to calculate the proper position of that mask dynamically. Other than that, you could only emulate the effect by not using one overlay, but multiple elements (at least four) that cover the viewport while leaving that rectangle area out.

Comment: (Both of those solutions might need to update properties/positions dynamically, if document scrolling has to be taken into account, too.)

Comment: OK but I need to have that header fixed.

Comment: @CBroe I was thinking about SVG mask but this is a lot of additional work. Can I solve it when header is fixed in some other way?

Comment: Dunno; not exactly sure how your fiddle reproduces the issue, resp. what’s supposed to be what in there. But z-index resp. stacking contexts are a complicated thing to begin with - I recommend a read of https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/ to fully understand what the issues are, and why just setting a high z-index simply _can’t_ achieve the desired result for all situations.